# Lognormal distribution using normal distribution inputs

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, lognormal-distribution

I'm simulating lognormal data in R log(Y), using the mean and standard deviation of Y. [This](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/06/04/simulate-lognormal-data-with-specified-mean-and-variance.html) article outlines it very well!

One step in the article I'm having trouble solving how it works though. Specifically, going from $m = \exp(μ + σ^2/2)$ and  $v = (\exp(σ^2) -1) \exp(2μ + σ^2)$ 
to

[image]

Can somebody guide me how they did this exactly? I know it's just algebra, just having some trouble figuring it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $v/m^2=\exp(\sigma^2)-1$

   Hence:

   $\exp(\sigma^2)=1+v/m^2$

   $\sigma^2=\ln(1+v/m^2)$

   $\sigma=\sqrt{\ln(1+v/m^2)}$
2. $m=\exp(\mu+\frac12 \sigma^2)$

   $=\exp(\mu)\exp(\frac12 \sigma^2)$

   $=\exp(\mu)\sqrt{\exp(\sigma^2)}$

   $=\exp(\mu)\sqrt{1+v/m^2}$

   So

   $\exp(\mu)=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1+v/m^2}}$

   $\mu=\ln{\frac{m}{\sqrt{1+v/m^2}}}$