# Convert from log-normal distribution to normal distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, sampling, lognormal-distribution

For purposes of sampling I have the variance **v** and mean **m** of a log-normal distribution, I don't want to directly sample from the log-normal distribution so my question is how can I convert this into a normal distribution and do sampling with this latter instead ?

Comment: see definition of lognormal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sample+normal+lognormal turns up answers already here on CV.

Comment: Notice that the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are usually taken to be the mean and SD of the **normal** distribution that gets exponentiated to make a lognormal.

Comment: An example answer is here (it even uses your $v$ and $m$ symbols): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158123/lognormal-distribution-using-normal-distribution-inputs/158138#158138

also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments
(scroll to near the bottom of that section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X \sim \mathrm{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y=e^X$, then $Y \sim \mathrm{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. The random variable $Y$ has mean $m=\mathbb{E}(Y)=\exp(\mu+\sigma^2/2)$ and variance $v=\mathrm{Var}(Y)=[\exp(\sigma^2)-1]\exp(2\mu+\sigma^2)$.

Solving for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ gives:

$$
\mu = \log(m) - \log(v/m^2+1)/2  \\
\sigma^2=\log(v/m^2+1)
$$

so you can sample from a Normal with this mean and variance, then exponentiate.